# How to calculate my sample size to establish my real-WR?

Tags: statistics, sampling, sampling-theory

I've been tracking for a period my hour rate on the game of poker and I want to know how much data I've to collect in order to establish my earning per hour. I've been searching online and when it comes to getting a handle on real winning rate potential 50k hands (1600 hours) is a starting point, 100k (3200 hours) is pretty good, and 500k+ (16200 hours+) is solid. But I'm not sure about this and I would like to calculate it myself. Any help?